# count number of nodes with a specific attribute value and node value/innerText in vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, count, innertext

I've read MSDN's article on node selection and lots of different posts on determining nodes with specific attributes and nodes with specific values, but I need to count the number of nodes that have both a specific attribute and a specific value.

To count the total number of nodes with a specific name value, I have this: 
 `Dim count6 As Integer = doc4.CreateNavigator().Evaluate("count(//TAG[@NAME='CURRENTTRANAMT'])")`

However, I need to know how many of the nodes counted above have a value/InnterText of 00000000000000.00

I'm working with a very oddly structured xml file, one like I've not seen before, and until now have been able to search and sort it as needed, but now I need to create a loop that stops when the value of the node with name CURRENTTRANAMT has the value of 00000000000000.00.

Is there a way to add the 00000000000000.00 value into my dim count6 or am I going to need a different approach?

Writing this out gave me a looping idea that may let me workaround this, but I'm still curious to know if the count above is possible.

Thanks for any suggestions,

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try following addition:

```
Dim count6 As Integer = doc4.CreateNavigator().Evaluate("count(//TAG[@NAME='CURRENTTRANAMT' and (@value = '00000000000000.00' or @innerText = '00000000000000.00')])")
```